# how to take user inputs in swift & xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I'm currently teaching myself swift and xcode to make apps, but I'm stuck at a part as how do I get input from the user, so for example how would I go about setting up a text field, than when the user inputs things into it I take what they put into it and show it somewhere else? Could someone either send me an example on how to do this or a link on where to find the information on how to do this.

thank you.

Comment: You mean you enter something into text field and pass it to another viewController?

Comment: Yes, For example if I enter my name into a UITextfield and press add, it redirects to a different VC and says Hello "Name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `prepareForSegue` for that.

sample code:

Your firstView when you want to enter user name:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var textF: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {

        performSegueWithIdentifier("next", sender: self)
    }
    //segue operation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

        if segue.identifier == "next" {
            // Create a variable that you want to send
            var text = textF.text

            // Create a new variable to store the instance of SecondViewController
            let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
            destinationVC.stringFromFirst = text
        }
    }

}
```

In your second view where you want to display user name:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!
    //This instance will hold value from firstView
    var stringFromFirst: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        lbl.text = "Hello \(stringFromFirst!)"
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

[HERE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=09510424869726749004) is sample project for more Info.

**UPDATE:**

As your error says:

> reason: 'Receiver () has no
>   segue with identifier 'next''

Means your `secondViewController` doesn't have segue with identifier name "next".

For that click on your segue and go to Attribute Inspector and give a identifier to your segue as shown into below image:

[image]

Go through my sample project and you will understand it easily.

Comment: I keep getting a Thread 1: signal SIGABART error. I've tried everything to fix it even straight copied the example, could you please help me through this error

Comment: Show me your crash log from console

Comment: 2015-09-13 15:42:01.404 input[549:36152] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<input.ViewController: 0x7f7fd95a99e0>) has no segue with identifier 'next''
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101f1cc65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                                                       0x0000000103a87bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
 2   UIKit

Comment: 0x00000001028ee473 -[UIViewController shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 0
 3   input                               0x0000000101d0f7a6 _TFC5input14ViewController9addButtonfS0_FPSs9AnyObject_T_ + 278
 4   input                               0x0000000101d0f826 _TToFC5input14ViewController9addButtonfS0_FPSs9AnyObject_T_ + 54
 5   UIKit                               0x00000001027bcd62 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75

Comment: 6   UIKit                               0x00000001028ce50a -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
 7   UIKit                               0x00000001028cd8d9 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
 8   UIKit                               0x0000000102809958 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
 9   UIKit                               0x000000010280a282 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 682
10  UIKit                               0x00000001027d0541 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
11  UIKit                            0x00000001027ddcdc _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 18265

Comment: 12  UIKit                               0x00000001027b859c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
 13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101e50431 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
 14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101e462fd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
 15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101e45934 __CFRunLoopRun + 868

Comment: 16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101e45366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
 17  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000105ef0a3e GSEventRunModal + 161
 18  UIKit                               0x00000001027bb8c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
 19  input                               0x0000000101d13cb7 main + 135
 20  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001041bd145 start + 1
 21  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)